# Steam Mobile Authenticator not working?

Tags: steam

So due to steam requiring the mobile authenticator for trades I got it about a month ago. It's a pain but I don't trade often, just use it when I log in the steam. Recently I tried to use a Jackpot site and it said I hadn't used my authenticator for 7 days and the trade would be held for 72 hours. Which obviously doesn't work in a jackpot. However, I traded completely fine without a wait or anything a couple days ago, but the trade was through steam. Now all my trades are still held for 72 hours, in steam or out of steam. This has been frustrating me for the longest time! If anyone knows how to fix this I would love you!

Comment: This is fairly old; but it was just bumped, so just a heads up for anyone having a lot of trouble with the mobile authenticator.  If you check off "Remember my password" (or whatever the button to that effect is on the steam login), you don't have to authenticate every login.  Sadly this only works well if you're not sharing your computer a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to get around this limitation. After you wait 7 days, you will no longer have trade holds.

The most likely cause of the sudden trade hold is because of a disable and re-enable of the mobile authenticator or multiple failed attempts at entering the authentication code.

Comment: Ok, I'll see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to remove the authenticator and re-add it?

> - Disable the authenticator (go to the Steam Guard menu and choose a different Steam Guard method)
> - Log out of your account (go to the Log Out menu on iOS, or go to Settings / Log Out on the Android app).

[Source](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8625-WRAH-9030#newphone)

Comment: I've tried that :/